# apppend or appendto function of jquery convert text data to lowercase

Tags: jquery, html, xml

Hi i am having data as the

```
var value=<userId>34</userId>
var xml1 = $.parseXML(myxmldata);
$(xml1).append(value) ;
```

and the output is as appended data is `<userid>34</userid>` in lower case.

and server not able to access this tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : create jquery object by puting tag in string and then use `append()`

```
var value=$('<userId>34</userId>');
var xml1 = $.parseXML(myxmldata);
$(xml1).append(value) ;
```

Comment: In case of `append`, `var value = $('<userId>34</userId>');` will work the same way as `var value = '<userId>34</userId>';` does.

Answer (score 0):

This Work for me

```
$(xml1).append($.parseXML(value).documentElement) ;
```